# How to switch headers using only CSS?

Tags: css

#### The effect I'm trying to get

I was looking at how [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) designed their header on their website and saw that it changes after scrolling it past the `hero` section **without using JavaScript**. It is more of an overlapping effect vs just a sticky scrollbar.

[image: GraphQL Navbar example]

---

#### What I've tried so far

I've looked through the source code and stylesheet to see how they accomplished this effect and don't see anything that stands out to me, such as `position: sticky;`.

I also tried to play around with the `z-index` of both headers but still can't figure out how they layered it to overlap like this.

The things that do stand out that they used are: `clip`, `z-index`, and `position: fixed;`.

Here is an attempt I made to recreate this effect:

```css
/* Basic styles just for visual */

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #aaa;
}

section {
  min-height: 1250px;
  padding: 100px;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Attempt at overlapping headers */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 10;
}

.hero {
  position: fixed;
  background: #171e26;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 450px;
  max-height: 900px;
  height: 65vh;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.hero .abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hero .header {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(23, 30, 38, 0.8), rgba(23, 30, 38, 0));
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    First Header
  </div>
</header>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="abs">
    <header>
      <div class="header-content">
        Header in hero
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
<section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, ipsum. Est exercitationem eum voluptates neque suscipit natus repudiandae perferendis minima ipsum eveniet possimus esse nam excepturi maxime, odit, debitis numquam.
</section>
```

This is somewhat close, but you can tell the top header is just staying white vs being transparent.

---

#### Summary question

Really, I don't need a full example back as an answer, although it is welcome. I really just want to understand how they did this.

How are they able to accomplish this using only CSS?

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Each navbar has a fixed position, but the second one (class .hero) has a negative top margin of 50px which equals the height of the navbar, so the second one appears first, and to cover the second nav bar. When you scroll up far enough, as in your image, the div that contains that nav bar, (the first one in the code) moves out of the viewport, revealing the second one.

Comment: Thank you @j08691. I did not see the negative top margin. Not sure what you mean by `so the second one appears first, and to cover the second nav bar`. Would you care to elaborate in an answer? I also noticed they are using `clip` to do the effect. If I remove that it does not work the same way.

Comment: @RobertTodar I'll see if I can come up with a more simple working example

Answer (score 1):

A basic example of how this can be achieved using two navbars with `absolute` and `fixed` positions. This, however, does not work with the hero section as GraphQL website has as both navbars are positioned at the top of the page.

```css
.show-when-scrolling {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Remain in position when scrolling */
  z-index: 1; /* Hide navbar under main navbar */
}

.main-nav {
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute; /* Show on top of other content */
  z-index: 2; /* Show main navbar on top of second navbar */
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* Remove browser default margin to fill whole screen */
  height: 200vh; /* Makes page scrollable */
}

/* Random styling */
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav main-nav">
  <a>My</a>
  <a>main</a>
  <a>navbar</a>
</div>

<div class="nav show-when-scrolling">
  <a>Visible</a>
  <a>when</a>
  <a>scrolling</a>
</div>
```

Another solution, for when you want to implement a hero section as in your example, can be done using `sticky` position.

```css
.show-when-scrolling {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Remain in position when scrolling */
  z-index: -1;
}

.main-nav {
  position: sticky; /* Remains inside wrapper, so it will be hidden when scrolled enough */
  top: 0; /* Stick to the top */
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* Remove browser default margin to fill whole screen */
  height: 200vh; /* Makes page scrollable */
}

/* Random styling */
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.top-section {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562347810-18a0d370ba36?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80)
}
```

```html
<div class="nav show-when-scrolling">
  <a>Visible</a>
  <a>when</a>
  <a>scrolling</a>
</div>
<div class="top-section">
  <div class="nav main-nav">
    <a>My</a>
    <a>main</a>
    <a>navbar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite the same effect as the overlap but appreciate showing other examples that are close alternatives to it.